# How can I build a overlapping search bar with a filter button

Tags: html, css, user-interface, bootstrap-4

[Desired Ui](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ssIzU.png)
I'm trying to make a search bar with a button to the right of it, in which both are halfway overlapping a banner. Above both of these is a title (One issue I'm having is the title covering the search bar when the page shrinks).
I have already made it, but it is far from mobile responsive. The most important thing I am struggling with is the button going to the next line when the page shrinks. The button needs to stay square so how do I make the search bar the only thing shrinking? Does anyone have any ideas on how to make this look good at all sizes?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```css
html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.root {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.header {
  height: 50%;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  font-size: 30px;
  border-bottom: solid 2px;
}

.search {
  z-index: 20;
  position: absolute;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 20px;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  height: 20px;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.search_main {
  background: white;
  width: auto;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  border: solid 2px;
}

.search_input {
  /*   border-radius: 20px; */
  border: solid 0px;
  outline: none;
  text-decoration: none;
  height: 100%;
  padding: 8px;
}

.btn {
  background: white;
  width: auto;
  /*   padding:10px; */
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  align-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  border-radius: 50%;
  /*   height:100%; */
  border: solid 2px;
  padding: 7px;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.ionicon {
  /*   width: 35px;
  height: 35px; */
  font-size: 25px;
  font-weight: 40;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>title</title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
  <script src="script.js"></script>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="root">
    <div class="header">
      Search from hundreds of recepies.
    </div>
    <div class="search">
      <div class="search_main"><input class='search_input' placeholder='Search...'></div>
      <div class="btn">
        <ion-icon name="filter-outline" class='ionicon'></ion-icon>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>



  <script type="module" src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.esm.js"></script>
  <script nomodule src="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@5.5.2/dist/ionicons/ionicons.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```